# Pin additional data (including a Verifiable Credential) to a x509 certificate

Tags: certificate

I am new to working with x509 certificates and I have a question (perhaps dumb)  about pinning additional data to it. I want to send some important data to a service.
The data payload includes

- x509 certificate
- A verifiable credential
- JSON payload

I would also like to encrypt this data so only a public key can decrypt it. I'll sign it with my private key. I need it to be base64 encoded so I can send it as query parameters

What is the right way to achieve this? Pin json and the verifiable credential to the certificate? Some sort of cross signing?

Comment: Why you want "pin" something. What for? What kind of service is? Just sign, enncrypt, encode and send each in separate parameter

Comment: Can I sign them all together in one parameter?

Comment: Wrap up with JSON or XML or whatever you like, encode and send

Comment: gotcha! I want to encrypt this payload as well. Basically, our customer will send us this JSON encrypted payload and we need to decrypt it. We have their public x509 certificate so should the customer sign with their private key and we use the x509 certificate to decrypt? Is there a better way to ensure this encrypted payload is freom a trusted customer?